# Extract text inside "<>" tag

Tags: xml, lua

I'm a noob using LUA. I'm breaking my head trying to extract some text in a XML inside this tags "<>"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejemplar gaceta="Gaceta de Notificaciones de la Dirección Divisional de Patentes" volumen="12 de mayo" fecha_puesta_circulacion="12 de mayo de 2022" schemaLocation="http://siga.impi.gob.mx/resources/xsd/gaceta.xsd">
  <seccion nombre="Solicitudes de Patentes">
    <ficha>
      <campo>
        <clave><![CDATA[Número del Oficio]]></clave>
        <valor><![CDATA[42207]]></valor>
      </campo>
      <campo>
        <clave><![CDATA[Fecha del Oficio]]></clave>
        <valor><![CDATA[10 de Mayo de 2022]]></valor>
      </campo>
      <campo>
        <clave><![CDATA[Descripción general del asunto]]></clave>
        <valor><![CDATA[Procede el otorgamiento.]]></valor>
      </campo>
```

I want to extract this text to put it on multiple variables

```
<ejemplar gaceta="Gaceta de Notificaciones de la Dirección Divisional de Patentes" volumen="12 de mayo" fecha_puesta_circulacion="12 de mayo de 2022" schemaLocation="http://siga.impi.gob.mx/resources/xsd/gaceta.xsd">
```

And finally obtain

```
gaceta = "Gaceta de Notificaciones de la Dirección Divisional de Patentes"
volumen = 12 de mayo
fecha_puesta_circulacion="12 de mayo de 2022"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier to extract information from XML documents if you use XML tools and APIs. The information that you are looking to extract are the values of different [attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Key_terminology).

You can select all of them from the `ejemplar` element with this XPath: `/ejemplar/@*`

If you just wanted the attribute named `gaceta`: `/ejemplar/@gaceta`

All attributes in the document? `//@*`

Not sure what the best libraries are for XML and XPath support in LUA, but some quick searches point to: https://github.com/bkersten/lua-xpath,

Comment: [This](https://github.com/manoelcampos/xml2lua) can be of help too.

Comment: Actually it works pretty well, i'm using the LUA included on MicroFocus IDOL and it has the xpath libraries on it

Answer (score -1):

Use `string.gmatch` to split string into `name=value` pairs

```lua
local str = [=[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejemplar gaceta="Gaceta de Notificaciones de la Dirección Divisional de Patentes" volumen="12 de mayo" fecha_puesta_circulacion="12 de mayo de 2022" schemaLocation="http://siga.impi.gob.mx/resources/xsd/gaceta.xsd">
  <seccion nombre="Solicitudes de Patentes">
    <ficha>
      <campo>
        <clave><![CDATA[Número del Oficio]]></clave>
        <valor><![CDATA[42207]]></valor>
      </campo>
      <campo>
        <clave><![CDATA[Fecha del Oficio]]></clave>
        <valor><![CDATA[10 de Mayo de 2022]]></valor>
      </campo>
      <campo>
        <clave><![CDATA[Descripción general del asunto]]></clave>
        <valor><![CDATA[Procede el otorgamiento.]]></valor>
      </campo>
]=]

local ejemplars = {}
for ejemplar in str:gmatch"<ejemplar (.-)>" do
   local vars = {}
   for name, value in ejemplar:gmatch'([%w_]+)="(.-)"' do
      vars[name] = value
   end
   table.insert(ejemplars, vars)
end

for j = 1, #ejemplars do
   print(ejemplars[j].gaceta)
   print(ejemplars[j].volumen)
   print(ejemplars[j].fecha_puesta_circulacion)
end
```

Comment: Please no -- terrible solution. Processing XML requires an XML parser. This code is full of bugs - it assumes that the XML is formatted precisely as shown in the example, and will fail if there is any slight change to the formatting. For example it assumes double-quotes rather than single quotes around the attribute values. (We get so many posts on SO asking "how can I output XML in the precise format that the calling application requires?"...)

Comment: @MichaelKay - My solution is quick and dirty, but pretty good for the OP's usecase.  For example, it is very unlikely that system generating XML will suddenly change double quotes into single quotes (or will change the format in any other way).  Of course, you need XML parser when parsing a file having unknown structure, but for this particular task it is overkill.  If you consider my solution as a general-purpose XML parser then yes, it is "full of bugs" :-)  But it is not a XML parser.

Comment: We know nothing about the OP's use case. We don't know where the XML is coming from, we don't know whether the code is going to be used once or to remain in production for 20 years, we don't know its performance or security or reliability requirements. Yes, there are some situations where buggy solutions are acceptable for a one-off task. Advising a buggy solution where we know nothing about the requirements is totally unprofessional, especially when advising a beginner.

Comment: @MichaelKay - We know the format currently used by the system OP uses to produce XMLs, this format is specified in the question.  And my solution is not "buggy" - it just relies on this format.  I should note again that your assumption that the system can suddenly change type of quotes is ridiculous.  Have you seen such change happened in real life? :-)

Comment: It's basic good software engineering practice to accept any input that conforms to the contract for the interface between two components, and the contract here says that it's XML, not "XML formatted according to the unwritten conventions of this particular example". Really, we get so many StackOverflow problems that result from people not following this basic engineering good practice.

Comment: Unreasonable overkill never was a good engineering practice.  This question does not ask to `accept any input that conforms to XML standard`.